# passport.js: remember me doesn't work in express app

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have implemented passport-local strategy in my application. Now I'm going to implement remember me functionality:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.post("/login", function (req, res, next) {
    var authFunction = passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    next(err);
                } else {
                    if (req.body.remember) {
                        req.session.cookie.originalMaxAge = 2592000000;
                    } else {
                        req.session.cookie._expires = false;
                    }
                    res.redirect("/");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    authFunction(req, res, next);
});
```

As you can see I set the `originalMaxAge`, but it doesn't work when I close and open the browser again.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Connect Documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) :

> **Session#cookie**
>
> Each session has a unique cookie object accompany it. This allows
>   you to alter the session cookie per visitor. For example we can
>   set req.session.cookie.expires to false to enable the cookie
>   to remain for only the duration of the user-agent.
>
> **Session#maxAge**
>
> Alternatively req.session.cookie.maxAge will return the time
>   remaining in milliseconds, which we may also re-assign a new value
>   to adjust the .expires property appropriately. The following
>   are essentially equivalent

According to this, you have to set `expires` and `maxAge` properties :

```
if (req.body.remember) {
    var oneHour = 3600000;
    req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + hour);
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = hour;
} else {
    req.session.cookie.expires = false;
}
```